# "The first time" vs. "at the first time" vs. "for the first time"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I have to arrange as a sequence some details about operations an 
ATM user will do to take cash.

Which of the following is or are grammatical?

> 1. The first time the user pushes the button, if the number he entered is not valid, then...
> 2. At the first time the user... (as the above)
> 3. For the first time...(as the above)

I would be inclined to choose the first... Am I right?

Comment: Where is the rest of the sentence? Without further context, two and three are not even an option, but I can think of context that could justify *for*. You might also be interested in our sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwighт: I edited my post. I suppose that now it's more clear.